# Is there anyway to show the loaded picture without using Loader when load the picture with URLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3

```
public class NewClass  extends Sprite 
{

    public function NewClass() 
    {
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        req.url = "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/708545main_pia16453-43_full.jpg";
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
         var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.load(req);
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    }

        //  Is there anyway to show the loaded picture without using Loader???
        private function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
                    var _ba:ByteArray = e.target.data as ByteArray;

                  /*                        var _l:Loader = new Loader;
                    _l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, onBytesLoaded);
                    _l.loadBytes(_ba);
        e.target.removeEventListener (Event.COMPLETE , onImageLoaded);*/

        }

        private function onBytesLoaded(e:Event):void 
         {
                    var _bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
                    trace(_bitmap.width, _bitmap.height );
                    addChild (_bitmap );
                    //
                    e.target.loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, onBytesLoaded);
         }  

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Only way I know is to drag the picture on stage in Flash and then convert it to MovieClip and check "Export for ActionScript" box and name the class(example "image"). After that you can do by the code below.

```
public class NewClass extends Sprite
{
    private var picture:image=new image();

    public function NewClass
{ 
    picture.width=100; //example
    picture.height=100; //example
    addChild(picture)
    }
 }
```